# ASP.NET (VB) array / list items added to JSON object are being duplicated

Tags: asp.net, arrays, json, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Class Farms

    Public Property farmID As Integer
        Get
            Return _sfarmID
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _sfarmID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _sfarmID As Integer

    Public Property farmName As String
        Get
            Return _farmName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _farmName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _farmName As String

End Class


Partial Class credentials_check_test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim result As String = "OK"
        Dim emailAddressEncrypted = "d2839280b3b1f3692a94ac76c6a5"
        Dim passwordEncrypted = "524efa0ab3c32c63b470efc4ec69"

        Dim objFarms = New List(Of Farms)()
        Dim farms = New Farms()

        farms.farmID = 1234
        farms.farmName = "One to Four Farm"
        objFarms.Add(farms)

        farms.farmID = 9876
        farms.farmName = "Nine to Six Farm"
        objFarms.Add(farms)

        Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                       New With {
                           result, emailAddressEncrypted, passwordEncrypted, .farmList = objFarms
                                                                         }, Formatting.Indented))

    End Sub

End Class
```

I cannot understand why the second farm object is being duplicated, instead of being simply added to the list.

Expected result should be (each farm appears only once):

`{
    "result": "OK",
    "emailAddressEncrypted": "d5d2839280b3b1f3692a94ac76c6a5b4",
    "passwordEncrypted": "75524efa0ab3c32c63b470efc4ec69e4",
    "farmList": [{
            "farmID": 1234,
            "farmName": "One to Four Farm"
        },
        {
            "farmID": 9876,
            "farmName": "Nine to Six Farm"
        }
    ]
}`

But my actual result is (note, farm id 9876 appears twice!):

`{
  "result": "OK",
  "emailAddressEncrypted": "d2839280b3b1f3692a94ac76c6a5",
  "passwordEncrypted": "524efa0ab3c32c63b470efc4ec69",
  "farmList": [
    {
      "farmID": 9876,
      "farmName": "Nine to Six Farm"
    },
    {
      "farmID": 9876,
      "farmName": "Nine to Six Farm"
    }
  ]
}`

So the Nine to Six Farm is appearing twice and there is no trace of the One to Four Farm.

I've been staring at this for hours, can anyone advise what am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only creating one `Farms` object.  This is the line that creates the object:

```
Dim farms = New Farms()
```

The `New` keyword is what tells it to create an object.  Since you never set it equal to a new object before filling it the second time, all you're doing is modifying (overwriting) the properties on the original object and then adding it to the list a second time.  The list, at that point just contains two references to the same object.

To fix it, you need to set it to a new object before filling it with the second set of data:

```
Dim farms = New Farms()
farms.farmID = 1234
farms.farmName = "One to Four Farm"
objFarms.Add(farms)

farms = New Farms()
farms.farmID = 9876
farms.farmName = "Nine to Six Farm"
objFarms.Add(farms)
```

Alternatively, you could use a different variable name:

```
Dim farms = New Farms()
farms.farmID = 1234
farms.farmName = "One to Four Farm"
objFarms.Add(farms)

Dim farms2 = New Farms()
farms2.farmID = 9876
farms2.farmName = "Nine to Six Farm"
objFarms.Add(farms2)
```

Or, better yet, don't make a variable at all and just use the object initialization syntax to populate the new object:

```
objFarms.Add(New Farms() With {.farmID = 1234, .farmName = "One to Four Farm"})
objFarms.Add(New Farms() With {.farmID = 9876, .farmName = "Nine to Six Farm"})
```

As David mentioned, this has nothing to do with JSON serialization.  If you viewed or output the contents of the `objFarms` list in any other way, you'd see the same duplication.  The reason it's happening is because you defined `Farms` as a `Class`, which makes it a reference type.  If you had defined it as a `Structure`, then it would be a value type (i.e. like a primitive).  If it was a structure, you don't need the `New` keyword, because every variable of that type would always be its own instance, and when you added it to the list, it would always be adding a copy rather than a reference.  I would strongly suggest that you do some research into the differences between value types and reference types in .NET.

On a side note, it's confusing having the class be named `Farms`.  I think you probably want that to be singular, since each instance of the class only holds information about a single farm.  By calling it `Farms`, it sounds like each one would contain a list of farms.  Also, since you aren't actually doing anything in the getters and setters of the properties, you could take advantage of auto-properties to shorten your code and make it easier to read and maintain:

```
Class Farm
    Public Property FarmID As Integer
    Public Property FarmName As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

You only have one `Farms` object:

```
Dim farms = New Farms()
```

Which you add to the list twice, and modify its properties twice.  That one object will always show the last values you set to it, and any reference to that same object (including list elements) will show that same state.

Create *two* objects in your list:

```
Dim farms = New Farms()

farms.farmID = 1234
farms.farmName = "One to Four Farm"
objFarms.Add(farms)

farms = New Farms() ' -- create a new one here

farms.farmID = 9876
farms.farmName = "Nine to Six Farm"
objFarms.Add(farms)
```

(Side note: This really has nothing to do with the JSON serialization.  Step through the code in a debugger and observe the runtime values of your objects and see what happens as soon as you set a property on `farms` the second time.)